# How to create organization chart in SharePoint?

Tags: chart, organization-browser

I want to create a organization chart in SharePoint.

It will have 6-7 levels and data of profile (like name, designation, level) are stored in list. Data is dynamic and can be changed after certain period so chart should reflect according to that.

How can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: what is your SharePoint version?

Comment: 2013. can be done using JS or jquery?

Comment: http://bloggerbrij.blogspot.com.au/2014/11/orgchart-using-jquery-and-sharepoint.html